# Ionic Problema data base

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

Good day I have the following problem with my Ionic apk, when it is developed it contains Database and the sqlite plugin, but when generating my apk normal entry and when I reentry it generates problem with the database.

The error that presents me when opening the new application from my cell phone

```
Error creating database
"plugin-not-installed"
```

but the sqlite plugin if installed before generating apk.

which can be the fault.

Comment: What is the output of `cordova plugin`

Comment: Tengo el cordova plugin instalado ,  el problema se presenta  al generar la apk,  la instalo en el celular  y me presenta esa falla ,  Error creatibg database "plugin-not-intalled".  esr Problema me presenta al tenerlo corriendo en celular Android
_______________________
 I have the cordova plugin installed, the problem arises when generating the apk, the installation in the cell phone and it presents me with that flaw, the creatibg database "plugin-not-intalled" error. esr Problem presents me when I have it running on Android cell

Comment: Show us the command that you are using in order to build the application.

Comment: this is.   ionic cordova build android

Comment: Try with `ionic cordova build android --prod`

Comment: it does not work